# How to pass variable consisting of list as argument to another python script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using below script to pass a list variable to another python script. Here i'm passing `a` as list variable.

**script test.py:**

```
import sys,os

a=[1,2,3,4,5]
os.system(f"python test2.py '{a}' ")
```

below script will receive the variable and try to print what ever is being passed to `test2.py`

**script test2.py:**

```
import sys

print("inside test4.py")
received_list=sys.argv
print(received_list)
print(sys.argv[0])
print(sys.argv[1])
```

I was trying to fetch complete list, but i'm getting only first element like this `'[1,`

**Actual output:**

```
inside test2.py
['test2.py', "'[1,", '2,', '3,', '4,', "5]'"]
test2.py
'[1,
```

**Expected output:**

```
inside test2.py
['test2.py', '[1,2,3,4,5]']
test2.py
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

I'm able to get the expected out put if I explicitly pass the list instead of variable i.e `os.system(f'python test4.py "[1,2,3,4,5]"')`

how can this be done by passing a variable.

Comment: I think `os.system(f"python test2.py {str(a)} ")` would do.

Comment: When you call os.system() you leave the Python zone and enter shell environment. The shell does not know about Python lists, all it sees is 5 arguments separated by spaces. You should have a look at modules and use `import`, that's not how we use other python scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

test.py

```
import sys,os
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
os.system("python test4.py "+",".join(map(str,a)))
```

test4.py

```
import sys, ast

print("inside test4.py")
received_list=sys.argv
print(received_list)
print(sys.argv[0])
print(list(ast.literal_eval(sys.argv[1])))
```

Comment: instead of eval you can use ast.literal_eval()